# Better way to type casting an object from one custom class to another

Tags: design, python

I have one  object, its class inherits all property from GUI class, that takes and some values and one function during instantiation, that handles click and upon receiving the click it calls the function which it received during instantiation.

Due to some reason, I need to convert this object to another type object, for converting I am using a function that copies all the values which is required to instantiate the another type object,.

Till now, I have never copied the function from former type to later as it was not required for instantiation . Due to some reason, I need to convert it back to former one, however, this time I can't do it as I don't have the same function which was required instantiation and for handling the click.

I can redesign the later class, that accepts the functions too during instantiation, which is not serving any purpose. However, I was wondering if there any better way to do this.

Comment: This question sounds very confusing to me. Maybe you can edit it and try to explain the details using code snippets or pseudo code?

Comment: Given that (1) Python uses duck-typing pervasively, and (2) Python code bases and frameworks tend to be completely source-available (you can literally browse through all of the code in your dependencies, irrespective of licensing), you might want to perform a cursory look at whether `isinstance` and typeclass comparisons were used properly in that code base.

Comment: Ask a better question, get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

If "being convertible to class A" is a requirement for class B, then the function **is** serving a purpose.

If you don't want to declare it for seemingly no reason, perhaps A and B can also be related by inheritance?

Comment: Sorry , I didn't understand your first line ? Could you please elaborate if possible for you ?

Comment: Even if the function is never called by code in objects of the other type, they still need it to pass it to the constructor of the former type. So in that sense, that class *does* need the function, therefore "accepting the function during instantiation serves no purpose" is not strictly true.

Comment: I got your point now. I want to know if this can be improved , If I am ready to redesign both class, or this is just fine.

Comment: @novice Have you tried passing in a `None` or an empty `Callable` and see what happens? Does that trigger some kind of validation failure in the code you're using? If so, focus your efforts in those things.